# I have a startup issue with Myeclipse2014,and I have no clue with it,I've been troubling for this

Tags: java

once I click it,it will just pop-up some warnings,it total make no sense to me,I do need some help,hope someone would know the reason of it,what cause that,and leave a comment let me know how to solve it,here are some sreenshots,this is one.
[once I click it,this will pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oFqM.png)

and then I click the button "确定"(sure),it will pop-up another thing,which I don't know if this's a warning,but anyway,I also have no clue with this one too.
[I click the button sure,this will pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4zsR.png)

by the way,my jdk version is 1.8,and it works,I can compile things with cmd.
Thanks first,hopefully someone could help me.